# How to set the notification just send once every year?

Tags: android, android-notifications, periodic-task

I want to send a notification when the time is between May 8 and May 12 just once every year.

But i stuck in compare with different year , it cause that will send notification every time when user start the application or reboot that if time is between May 8 and May 12.

It's confuse me with a lots of hours , some one can teach me how to fix the issue , that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My manifests:

```
<application>
        <!--  -->
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmSetting.PlayReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="play_hskay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- -->
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmSetting.AlarmInitReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

My main activity will save the `boolean` and `year`:

```
//Setting
public void startAlarmSetting() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("msg", "play_hskay");

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    //Save the time when user start application
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("time", MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.edit().putLong("saveTime", time)
            .putInt("saveFirstYear",2017)
            .putInt("saveNextYear",year)
            .putBoolean("saveBoolean",true)
            .apply();
}
```

My PlayReceiver:
this line of code `if ( neverSend || !(firstYear == nextYear)){` confused me

```
    public class PlayReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private Context context;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Starting playReceiver TDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Bundle bData = intent.getExtras();

            // load current time
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
            //set first time
            Calendar firstLimit = Calendar.getInstance();
            firstLimit.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
            firstLimit.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);
            firstLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
            firstLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            firstLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
            //set second time
            Calendar secondLimit = Calendar.getInstance();
            secondLimit.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
            secondLimit.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);
            secondLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
            secondLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            secondLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("time", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean neverSend = preferences.getBoolean("saveBoolean",false);
            //int firstYear = preferences.getInt("saveFirstYear",0);
            int firstYear = 2017;
            int nextYear = preferences.getInt("saveNextYear",0);
            //neverSend will be true when first time.
            if ( neverSend || !(firstYear == nextYear)){

            if (current.after(firstLimit) && current.before(secondLimit)) {
               if (bData.get("msg").equals("play_hskay")) {
                sendNotification();
     //change the nextYear and save it.
     Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                    int sendYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    preferences.edit().putInt("saveNextYear",sendYear).putBoolean("saveBoolean",false)
                            .apply();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "out of the period", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
}
```

My AlarmInitReceiver:

```
public class AlarmInitReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Start~~~~TDU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("time", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long setTime = preferences.getLong("saveTime", 0);

        Intent intentForSetTime = new Intent(context, PlayReceiver.class);
        intentForSetTime.putExtra("msg", "play_hskay");

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentForSetTime, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setTime, pi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably this is because You do `.putBoolean("saveBoolean",true)` every time when user start application.

Comment: Oops , you remind me another issue :(  , i working on it try to find solution , i try it now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061653/run-a-piece-of-code-only-once-when-an-application-is-installed

Comment: Thanks Andrii , your remind me another issue , and i find the solution from that link now.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because You do `.putBoolean("saveBoolean",true)` every time when user start application.